# Counting nodes in a linked list

Tags: c#

Say I have a small linked list like this:

```
var curr = Names
        .Create("name1")
        .Previous("name2")
        .Previous("name3")
        .Previous("name4")
        .Previous("name5");

private Names(Names next, string person)
{
    Next = next;
    Person = person;
}

public Names Next { get; }
public string Person { get; }

public Names Previous(string person)
{
    return new Names(this, person);
}

public static Names Create(string person)
{
    return new Names(null, person);
}
```

I would like to be able to count both left and right in `curr` so I have a `FromRight` method which will return the name from the right side, given an int. I'm thinking the easiest way is to make a helper function for counting the number of names, but any hint on how I could do that?

I'm pretty certain on how I can count from the left, but from the right is a little more troublesome for me.

```
public string FromRight(Names names, int numberFromRight)
{
    var nameCount = Count(names);

    //Counting from the right in Names

    return "";
}

private int Count(Names names)
{
    int count = 0;

    //Some counting logic here

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Why are you wtiting a linked list in C#? Use `List <T>` from the BCL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) which is like the linked list your have but it has a `previous` and a `next` so you can move up and down the list, and you can track the `head` and `tail` of the list allowing you to easily count from one end or the other.

In response to your comments, you could count from the current node to the end of the list and then subtract that number from the length of the list. This assumes you are tracking the length of the list.

Comment: I have been considering using a doubly linked list, but I was hoping for a simpler solution. Something with counting how many names there are in it, and putting them in a list or something and then count through the list instead.

Comment: @Left4Cookies Does your list only have unique entries? What happens if you get a duplicate, how do you know which one you are counting to? I think the doubly linked list is the tried and tested solution to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: To be fair, this should be a comment, not an answer. You'll get a lot of downvotes for this.

Comment: @GregB That's a fair problem to consider, but for this problem, I'm making the assumption here that all entries are unique.